# WCF Defining Interface Contract in WSDL

Tags: wcf, soap

I am building a proof of concept WCF service and am intentionally building out all interfaces to avoid providing any concrete implementation until necessary.  I would like to send the resulting contract (including message definitions) to another team to start building against the contract I am building, but the message parameters are not being serialized unless I provide a class decorated with the DataContractAttribute.  Is there a way for me to continue using loosely-coupled interfaces to define my contract or do I need to build out all of my messages using classes instead?

*Example service*

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
  [OperationContract]
  ITestResponse TestOperation(ITestRequest request);
}

public interface ITestRequest
{
  string Message { get; set; }
}

public interface ITestResponse
{
  bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

*Example XSD definition*

```
<xs:element name="TestOperation">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <!--I want this to be a reference to a complex type with definition of it's members-->
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="result" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you a must use a type that implements the interface, not the interface itself. As you've probably found out, you can't use DataContract on an interface.

The WCF serializer was designed to use concrete types because it must translate them in XML Schema based types. XML Schema does not have the notion of an "interface" as defined in .NET languages. The soap standard describes "types" in WSDL using XML Schema so they can be consume by any client written in any language that "knows" how to translate XSD's into appropriate constructs for that language.